# Method/Function arguments: Value then index or vice versa

Tags: function, methods

Which would you do:

```
setter(index, value)
```

or

```
setter(value, index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the first. I normally put the high level argument first, i.e. the index decides where to place the value in.

From a computer's perspective: first you need the location of where to store, when that is found, the value can be set.

It is similar as setting a property of e.g. an element of a car:

SetWheelDiameter(CarModel model, Part.Wheels, Wheel.Diameter, 19.0) 
Parameters are from high level to low level.

Answer (score 0):

Googling:

```
"T value int index"
```

suggests that it is a lot more common than:

```
"int index T value"
```